# Confused with format( ) in python doc

Tags: python

I'm not sure about python doc:

[**format(value[, format_spec])**](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#format)

```
A call to format(value, format_spec) is translated to
type(value).__format__(format_spec) which bypasses the
instance dictionary when searching for the value’s 
__format__() method.
```

Is it a typo? I think it should be translated to:

```
type(value).__format__(value, format_spec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The following code...

```
format(foo, "bar")
```

invokes...

```
type(foo).format(foo, "bar")
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes; the documentation of the [`__format__` special method](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#object.__format__) has signature:

```
object.__format__(self, format_spec)
```